# Rails 3: creating a validation with :if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, virtual-attribute

Hi I'm trying to setup a validation that is only called in a specific form view, to do this I'm trying to create a hidden_field  for a virtual attribute on the form and set this to a value, then validate :if the virtual attribute equals the value.

So far I have:

```
## user model 

validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, :if => :confirmation_validation 

attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, 
 :remember_me, :name, :avatar, :username, :bio, :confirmation_validation

def confirmation_validation
 # not sure what goes here???
end


## form view


<%= form_for(resource, :validate => true, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<p><%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %></p>

<p><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
<% f.hidden_field :confirmation_validation, :value => 100%></p>

<p><%= f.submit "Update" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The value of the `confirmation_validation` hidden field should be included in the `params` hash, and also set the virtual attribute accordingly. Therefore, you can probably simply check whether or not the value has been set:

```
validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, :if => :should_confirm?

def should_confirm?
  confirmation_validation == '100' # Value of the hidden field as set in the form
end
```

Comment: Hey, the above is showing an error for me and the error is given below.
Cant mass-assign proetected attributes. Why?

Comment: @Rajesh Add :password_confirmation to your attr_accessible.

Answer (score 5):

write one line code, it could help you to organize your code in simple.

```
validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, :if => lambda {|u| confirmation_validation == '100'}
```

or

```
validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, :if => Proc.new {|u| confirmation_validation == '100'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This response is very late, but for future SO viewers, I think the answer to @Rajesh question

> Hey, the above is showing an error for me and the error is given below. Cant mass-assign protected attributes. Why?

Is that you need to remove the hidden field you are using as a flag from the params hash before it's assigned to the record. Something like

```
params.reject{|p| p == name_of_hidden_field}
```